# Scheduled mail and reminders to groups

Tags: civievent, civimail

I'm working on setting up a weekly newsletter in CiviCRM (v 5.45.3 along with Drupal 9.3.6), and the more I look the more confused I am about how to scheduled mail works. It's hard to know what documentation and/or comments are actually current.

As I understand it, when you schedule an email for a group (whether it is a standard group or a Smart group) that email is created for the members of the group *at that moment.* In other words, anyone joining that group later on wouldn't receive the scheduled email. Is that still correct?

If it is, how do Event notifications work? When we create an event, and setup the reminder notifications, no one is a participant yet. So those *must* be added on the fly, right? I just want to make sure that I'm understanding it correctly!

Then when I get to the actual work that I'm trying to do - creating a weekly newsletter that people can subscribe to - I'm kind of lost. It seems like the sort of functionality that would be in CiviCRM already, but I can't see how to have a dynamic group of subscribers that can join and leave (I had planned on doing that through their Drupal profile) that will receive an email each week that I schedule in advance.

I feel like I must be missing something about how this is supposed to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most current and accurate documentation is https://docs.civicrm.org.

You're correct that a mailing's recipient list is calculated at the time the mail is composed, but you can install the [Recalculate Recipients](https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-recalculate-recipients) extension to change this behavior.

If I understand your question correctly, your needs would be met by installing Recalculate Recipients.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestion and the confirmation. I looked at the Recalculate Recipients option, but I'm always reluctant to use a module not updated recently (last update was 3 years ago).

I think I'm going to try to work this out on the Drupal side instead.

Comment: it could just be the extension is 'solid' and doesn't need updates for the sake of them. those developers are known and trusted

Comment: @zip_000 I use this extension in production on multiple sites.